# OpenGL ES VBO glgeterror 4242512 - what is it?

Tags: android, opengl-es, vbo

Hello I get "glgeterror 4242512", my code is:

```
    if (bUseVBO) {
        //gl11
        GL11 gl11 = (GL11)gl;
        int[] buffer = new int[1];

        gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
        textureBufferIndex = buffer[0];

        Log.e("error", buffer+" "+(gl11==null)+" ERR "+gl.glGetError());



        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBufferIndex);
        gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoords.length * 4, mTexBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
```

**edit:** if I call this on: **onSurfaceCreated** then everything go fine, i get a glgeterror 0, that is perfect.

If I start this call from a Thread, then I get this number "4242512" , and textureBufferIndex will be null too. Why?

Comment: Does Logcat print `glgeterror 4242512`?

Comment: gl.glGetError() returns that value

Comment: Why do you call it from another `Thread`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are calling OpenGL functions without a OpenGL context made current in the thread. You "main" thread has a OpenGL context and thus GL calls work without a problem, but your "other" thread doesn't have a GL context, and GL calls fail.

Comment: One point to add: It doesn't help to pass a `GL` reference when he's constructing a new `Runnable`/`Thread` - that's a common mistake.